# OpenLayers Map with toolbar not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, openlayers

I am trying to create a simple OpenLayers based map with a toolbar at the top of the screen.  I want the toolbar and map to be centered with a margin/border around each element and no scroll bars.  I will be eventually adding buttons to the toolbar but first I would like to get the layout nailed down.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.12/OpenLayers.js"></script>

        <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%
            margin: 0;
            background-color: black;            
        }

        #toolbar {
            border: solid 1px #999;
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 3%;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        #map {
            border: solid 1px #999;
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 95%;

        }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
            var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
            map.addLayer(osm);
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="toolbar"></div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is how a jsfiddle of your code looks like. I see some margins around map and tool bar. or are you looking for something elsE? http://jsfiddle.net/jq3YL

Comment: Yes I have margins but they are not consistent, the toolbar is too long and they are horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

Comment: so its just a css issue. check this fiddle is that okay?
http://jsfiddle.net/jq3YL/1/. Let me know if that works for you. I will make it into an answer.

Comment: okay I have made it into an answer. Please mark it accepted if it solves your problem. So others can lean form the same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jq3YL/1/) from comments. I just chenged the css to this:

```
 html, body {
            height: 96%;
            background-color: black;            
        }

        #toolbar {
            border: solid 1px #999;
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 3%;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        #map {
            border: solid 1px #999;
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```